# How to add markers and set custom tap events on markers with Google Maps Plugin?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I have a list of markers like this

```
List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[
    new Marker("1", "Name 1", 28.421364, 77.333804,
        color: Colors.amber),
    new Marker("2", "Name 2", 28.418684, 77.340417,
        color: Colors.purple),
  ];
```

And the basic code to show and draw the map

```
class  HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(11.052992, 106.681612),
    zoom: 11,
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I add markers from my `List<Marker>` to Google Maps and add `onTap` method to those markers?

Comment: Please vote and mark my answer as solved if you have no further questions about this and you think my answer is useful.

Answer (score 1):

As with google_maps_flutter 0.3.0, marker api has [changed](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#030). Before 0.3.0, you have to add your markers on controller like that.

```
mapController.addMarker(
  MarkerOptions(
    position: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462),
  ),
);
```

After the change on marker api,GoogleMap widget has a property named markers which takes Set of markers, not list of Markers. So you can give a set of markers to your GoogleMap widget. Also markers have onTap property for tapping.