# How to set custom tap events on markers with Google Maps Plugin?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

How can I add Tap Events for Google Maps Marker?

This is my list marker information

```
List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[
    new Marker("1", "Great", 11.052992, 106.681612,
        color: Colors.green, draggable: true),
         new Marker("1", "Great", 11.052994, 106.681613,
        color: Colors.red, draggable: true)
  ];
```

And I draw Google map on screen by `displayMap()`

```
displayMap() {
    mapView.show(new MapOptions(
        mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition:
            new CameraPosition(new Location(11.052992, 106.681612), 3.0),
        showUserLocation: false,
        ));`

   ` mapView.onMapTapped.listen((tapped) {
      mapView.setMarkers(markers);
      mapView.zoomToFit(padding: 100);
    });
  }
```

I tried add `mapView.onMapTapped.listen((tapped)` to draw the marker but I can't add this on each marker. It's mean when I tap on the marker. Some event will called. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add markers and set custom tap events on markers with Google Maps Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275505/how-to-add-markers-and-set-custom-tap-events-on-markers-with-google-maps-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

Marker API was changed on ^0.3.0+1, so you can easily use onTap() method for that.

```
Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId("id"),
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker(),
  position: LatLng(lat, long), 
  //use that
  onTap: () {
   yourMethod();
  }

),
```